# multiple javascript onchange events, same script fetching different mysql results

Tags: javascript, onchange

I have a javascript that is executed with the onchange event.

```
onchange="showUser(1, this.value)"
```

The Javascript calls a php page which executes a mysql query and displays the results on the current page.

The javascript works perfectly however I want to duplicate the javascript to run a different query and display the results on the existing page.

I have a table for orders, when I insert an order in the first column, I want the onchange even to trigger two scripts, one to pull and display product details in the second column and the other to pull and show the selling units in the third column.

**my javascript is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function showWhse(userNumber, str) 
  { 
    if (str=="") 
    { 
      document.getElementById("whse" + userNumber).innerHTML=""; 
      return; 
    }   
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    { 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
      { 
        document.getElementById("whse" + userNumber).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
      } 
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true); 
    xmlhttp.send(); 
  }
</script>
```

**the complete PHP Page is:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sales Portal</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function showUser(userNumber, str) 
  { 
    if (str=="") 
    { 
      document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=""; 
      return; 
    }   
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    { 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
      { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
      } 
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true); 
    xmlhttp.send(); 
  }
</script>

</head>
<body topmargin=0>

<form name="orderform" id="orderform" action="newsale.php" method="post">

<table border=1>    

<tr>
<td>Product Code</td>
<td>Description</td>
<td>Warehouse</td>
<td>Selling Units</td>
</tr>
<tr id="r1">  
    <td width=100>
        <input size=10  type=number id=sku1 name=sku1 onchange="showUser(1, this.value)">
    </td>
    <td width=280>
        <div align="left" id="txtHint1">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td width=100>
        <div align="left" id="whse1">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td width=100>
        <div align="left" id="su1">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r2">  
    <td>
        <input size=10  type=number id=sku2 name=sku2 onchange="showUser(2, this.value)">
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left" id="txtHint2">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left" id="whse2">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td width=100>
        <div align="left" id="su2">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r3">  
    <td>
        <input size=10  type=number id=sku3 name=sku3 onchange="showUser(3, this.value)">
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left" id="txtHint3">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left" id="whse3">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td width=100>
        <div align="left" id="su3">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r4">  
    <td>
        <input size=10  type=number id=sku4 name=sku4 onchange="showUser(4, this.value)">
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left" id="txtHint4">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left" id="whse4">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td width=100>
        <div align="left" id="su4">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**and the php file that executes the mysql query is:**

```
<?php
 $q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'unilekxy_UL', 'Unilever2011');
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("unilekxy_unilever", $con);


$sql="SELECT Category, Description,SellingUnits,Grouping,CasesPerPallet,ShrinksPerPallet FROM skudata WHERE packcode = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows==0){echo "<font color=red><b>NOT A VALID PRODUCT CODE</b></font>";} else {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<font color=red>".$row['Description']."</font>, ";
   if($row['SellingUnits']=="CS"){echo "<font color=red>".$row['CasesPerPallet']."</font> ";} elseif($row['SellingUnits']=="SHR") {echo "<font color=red>".$row['ShrinksPerPallet']."</font> ";}
   }}

mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

ideally I can use this script to fetch and display the product details, selling units and warehouse information once the user inputs the product code, as per below image:
[image]

How can I edit or duplicate the javascript in order for 1 onchange event to action this? I find that if I duplicate the entire sript, only the last instance is executed, I assume because the variables being used are the same with the unchanged script?

Thanks in advance for the help,
Ryan

**ADDITION**

I have made the changes to the javascript as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function showUser(userNumber, str) 
  { 
    if (str=="") 
    { 
      document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=""; 
      return; 
    }   
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    { 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
      { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
      } 
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true); 
    xmlhttp.send(); 

var responseText = xmlhttp.responseText; 
var description = responseText.substring(13, responseText.indexOf(",Warehouse:")); 
var warehouse = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(",Warehouse:")+11, responseText.indexOf(",SellingUnits:")); 
var sellingUnits = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(",SellingUnits:")+14); 

document.getElementById("whse" + userNumber).innerHTML = warehouse; 
document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML = description; 
document.getElementById("su" + userNumber).innerHTML = sellingUnits;
  }
</script>
```

How do I call these values to display in seperate columns? warehouse, description and sellingunits?

I presume I need to call these values from within my table html, how do I do this?

Thanks again, Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, edit your php file that executes the sql query to return all three values and remove any html formatting. The following does it by putting all values into a single string. If you know JSON for php, then you should use that instead.

```
<?php
 $q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'unilekxy_UL', 'Unilever2011');
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("unilekxy_unilever", $con);


$sql="SELECT Category, Description,SellingUnits,Grouping,CasesPerPallet,ShrinksPerPallet FROM skudata WHERE packcode = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows==0){echo "<font color=red><b>NOT A VALID PRODUCT CODE</b></font>";} else {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
   echo "Description:" . $row['Description'] . ",Warehouse:" . $row['Warehouse'] . ",SellingUnits:" . $row['SellingUnits'];
 }
}

mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Next, edit the showUser function to parse the `xmlhttp.responseText` to separate each value and set them to the desired div locations.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function showUser(userNumber, str) 
  { 
    if (str=="") 
    { 
      document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=""; 
      return; 
    }   
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    { 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
      { 
        //document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        var responseText = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var description = responseText;
        var warehouse = "";
        var sellingUnits = "";
        if (responseText.indexOf("NOT A VALID") == -1)
        {
          description = responseText.substring(13, responseText.indexOf(",Warehouse:")); 
          warehouse = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(",Warehouse:")+11, responseText.indexOf(",SellingUnits:")); 
          sellingUnits = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(",SellingUnits:")+14); 
        }

        document.getElementById("whse" + userNumber).innerHTML = warehouse; 
        document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML = description; 
        document.getElementById("su" + userNumber).innerHTML = sellingUnits;

      } 
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true); 
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

At this point, you should not need to make any other changes as the single call to `showUser(1, this.value)` will update all three fields.

Keep in my mind that it is always good to separate your user interface formatting code, `<font>`, from your SQL select statements as I have done above. In addition, it is always good to execute as few SQL queries as possible.

For more information about the `indexOf` and `substring` methods, see [JavaScript String Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Please note that I did not test any of this code, so there may be spelling mistakes or incorrect syntax.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer if everything is working for you.

Comment: did I put the changes to the javascript in the right place? How do I call these variables or outputs from within my html table syntax? Thanks,

Comment: You were a little off on where to put it. I made my answer clearer on where things must go.

Comment: Legendary!!! Thanks for the assistance. I truly appreciate your time! Time to do my learning now to ensure I understand what you have taught me! Go well, Ryan

Comment: sorry one more issues/question. if an incorrect packcode is entered, and the mysql result is 'NOT A VALID PRODUCT CODE', the output destorys the table structure. it ends up in column 4 under selling units. How can this be outputted to the description column? thanks again,